# Restarting an exited thread in Common Lisp Bordeaux Threads?

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp

Is there a way to restart a thread that has completed its task, to avoid the overhead of creating a new thread for the next task? (Note that all other processors/threads will be busy, and `(not (bt:thread-alive-p thread)` signals when the thread is dead.) For example, I've tried bt:interrupt-thread on the completed thread, but that doesn't work:

```
* (defparameter *x* 0)
*X*
* (let ((thread (bt:make-thread (lambda () (setf *x* (loop for i from 1 to 10 sum i))))))
    (sleep 1)
    (print *x*)
    (bt:interrupt-thread thread (lambda () (setf *x* (loop for i from 1 to 100 sum i))))
    (sleep 1)
    (print *x*))

55
debugger invoked on a SB-THREAD:INTERRUPT-THREAD-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10012E0613}>:
  Interrupt thread failed: thread #<THREAD "Anonymous thread" FINISHED 
values: 55 {1005D410D3}> has exited.
```

Also, is there a way to access the result (in the thread) returned from the function passed to bt:make-thread, to avoid having to communicate via a global variable, as in the example above?

Comment: @davypough You forgot to put a lock around `(setf *x*` but it doesn't matter for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's finished, it's finished.  The usual technique is to have the threads run a loop which waits for some work on some kind of channel.

Libraries such as [lparallel](http://www.lparallel.org) or [chanl](https://github.com/zkat/chanl) may help a lot.

For example, you could use `chanl` like this:

```
(defun parallel-mayhem (fun count)
  (let* ((start-chan (make-instance 'chanl:channel))
         (results-chan (make-instance 'chanl:channel)))
    (loop :repeat count
          :do (chanl:pexec ()
                (chanl:send start-chan "starting")
                (chanl:send results-chan (funcall fun))))
    (loop :repeat count
          :collect (chanl:recv start-chan))
    (format t "All started.")
    (loop :repeat count
          :collect (chanl:recv results-chan))))
```

Under the hood, `chanl` uses a simple thread pool.  You could take a look at how it does it, it is quite concise and readable.